# MicroSD cards stopped working after OSX 10.9 installation, why?

Tags: macos, bug

I don't know yet whether this is a problem with OSX 10.9 but I am unable to read the cards in my MBA after installation of 10.9. Any solution for this yet?

Comment: No answer, but I'd thought I'd chime in and say I have the same problem. Same SD card works fine on my 10.8 machine at work.

Comment: @DaleSattler Luckily, I am still able to read the cards through the USB-cable to my Sony Nex -- a bit irritating though that I need to read through USB with some external device.

Answer (score 1):

Are they NTFS formatted?  I am having trouble with flash drives that are NTFS formatted.  I use the free NTFS-3G software and am guessing that's the issue.  One post here seems to echo that sentiment:

[CNET NTFS-3G user review](http://download.cnet.com/NTFS-3G/3000-2094_4-10913782.html#rateit)

Also, found these Apple support posts where people indicate their problem is solved with NTFS-3G and Mavericks

https://discussions.apple.com/message/17356645#17356645

http://osxfuse.github.io/

Comment: My friend said that OSX really destroys the cards coming from Sony cameras, somehow tries to format them or something. I don't know what he meant but this may be related thing...

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue - this helped me: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbc0l-t3f1Q

Comment: Perhaps useful +1 for someone with MPro but not working with MBA 2012 and MBA 2013 with the newest OSX.